# With entity framework, how do I force a sql datatype for my string member

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a product class, for which the ManufacturerNumber gets generated as nvarchar(max) - how would I go about forcing the code-first framework to make it nvarchar(255)

```
public class Product : BaseEntity
{
    public string ManufacturerNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorate the property with `StringLength` attribute.

```
public class Product : BaseEntity
{
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string ManufacturerNumber { get; set; }
}
```